# Is it possible to get ionic's SCSS stylesheets in a meteor build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ionic-framework, npm

Simple problem here. I want to use the scss from ionic. So, I do the following in my package.json.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "postinstall": "ionic start ./imports/ui/ionic --appname test --no-cordova"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ionic": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

This will create a new ionic project which I can take the SCSS from

```
@import "{}/imports/ui/ionic/scss/ionic.test.scss";
```

However, as soon as I try `npm run`, it hangs for a very long time and never completes. `du -sh` says that the node_module for ionic is almost 150MB (which is ridiculous).

I am implementing the ionic javascript functionality myself through blaze, so don't need that. Essentially, what I am really after is something like [materialize-scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/materialize-sass) is to the Materialize framework, just the SCSS.

Is there any way to retrieve the SCSS files for ionic with NPM, without the other superfluous data?